# Youtube API returning unlisted videos

Tags: android, youtube-api, playlist

In my app I use the YouTube API. I got the "uploads" related playlist of a channel resource, and then list all videos.

This worked fine for some time, but now, this playlist is returning 'unlisted' videos like this:

```
"status": {
  "privacyStatus": "unlisted"
}
```

Is there a way to filter these videos? I thought they were 'hidden', but they do show up...

**Edit**: It is even returning private videos:

```
"status": {
  "privacyStatus": "private"
}
```

Comment: They're not hidden to you -- are you the channel owner?

Comment: No, I'm not the owner.

Comment: whoever authorizes the your app to control his channel, your app acts like them, acts s the owner. That's how the authorization works.

Comment: I'm not using auth on my app... I'm just listing one specific channel. Even in google website, when I click Try it, i can see unlisted videos!

Comment: Something changed in the last few days. **Even when you are *NOT* the owner of a channel, private and unlisted playlist items are being returned by a playlist items query.** A subsequent videos list query will return unlisted videos as if they are public, but private videos are not returned. It's screwing up the `totalResults` count of the playlist items. You don't know how many public/private/unlisted playlist items are included in the count. 

I tried using the `fields` query parameter with variations on `items[status/privacyStatus='public'],items(id,contentDetails,status)`, to no avail.

Comment: Yes, it changed in the last few days. This was not the expected behavior... I changed my app to filter out videos that are not 'public', but I also think that it is not the best solution. We should have a way to filter them on the playlist items query.

Comment: As of a couple hours ago, the API has changed back to the previous behavior for me. I once again only get public videos and an accurate public video count returned by the playlist items query.

Comment: I having the same issue at the moment for one of the channels I am querying. I am authorised as the owner of the channel, but I don't want to query unlisted or private videos. I am not sure how to proceed with this as there are thousands of unlisted videos. How can I contact YouTube support if this is a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are the owner of that channel it returns all the videos available. IF you were trying to see someone else's uploads, it would show only public ones.

Look at [my open source project: Android Direct Lite](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java#L466) to see, how I show only public ones.

Comment: See my comment on the question. Private and unlisted playlist items are being returned for channels you do **not** own.

Comment: (1) Seeing unlisted videos was not normal or expected last week (using API v3), so it raises the questions, how long will it be this way? Is it deliberate, or accidental and will change again? (2) If you batch your queries to do the minimal work possible, you request only the playlist items for a single page at a time (using a `pageToken`), and then request only the videos for those items. Your approach is suboptimal, in that it requires you to download all playlist items up front to filter and get an appropriate count. It would be better to simply allow a filter on the playlist items query.

Comment: This should've been fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya the link is not working anymore. Could you please update it if possible? Thanks