# YouTube API - Fetching playlistItems do not return unlisted items

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

Using the instructions here, I was able to get a list of all videos on a channel on *except* videos which are unlisted:
[Youtube Api to fetch all videos on a Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel)

The YouTube API documentation is not clear on whether I was able to retrieve unlisted channel using the playlistItems request, and this post seems to indicate that the behavior has changed multiple times: 
[Youtube API returning unlisted videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321711/youtube-api-returning-unlisted-videos?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Is there any solution on being able to retrieve a full list unlisted videos from the API from the channel? Also, for this specific channel, this API account is connected to the YouTube brand account as a Manager, and I'm not sure whether that changes the behavior of the API.